# WPF TextBox Binding ElementName null?

Tags: wpf, binding, elementname

I have a ListBox control with TypeUsers.When I select some record in Listbox and update Name in TextBox the Name property/textbox return always null. Never take value from TextBox, always null ?

[Image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ0xt.jpg)

This is my code

```
<ListBox x:Name="LstTypeUsers"
             Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"
             Width="220" Height="120"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             ItemsSource="{Binding TypeUsers}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name">
</ListBox>

 <TextBox 
             Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
             x:Name="txtName"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=LstTypeUsers, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"/>

<Button 
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="100" Height="30"
            Command="{Binding UpdateTypeUserCmd}" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="20,90,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/Save.png" />
                <TextBlock Width="55" Height="18" ><Run Text="   "/><Run Text="Update"/></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

**EDIT**

```
// Model class
public class UserType: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    private int usertypeId;
    public int UserTypeId 
    { 
     get 
     {
         return this.usertypeId;
     }
     set
     {
         this.usertypeId = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("UserTypeId");
     }
    }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    private string name;
    public string Name
    { 
     get 
     {
         return this.name;
     }
     set
     {
         this.name = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Name");
     }
    }

    [Required]
    private bool status;
    public bool Status
    { 
     get 
     {
         return this.status;
     }
     set
     {
         this.status = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Status");
     }
    } 

    public virtual ObservableCollection<User> User { get;   private set; }

    public UserType()
    {
        this.User = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    }
}

 // ViewModelBase class
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

// UserTypeViewModel

public class UserTypeViewModel

private UserType _userType;
private ObservableCollection<UserType> _UserTypeList;

// Constructor
public UserTypeViewModel()
{
   _userType = new UserType();
   _UserTypeList = new ObservableCollection<UserType>(GetUserTypeAll());
}

public ObservableCollection<TypeUsers> TypeUsers
{
  get
  {
     return _UserTypeList;
  }
  set
  {
     _UserTypeList = value;
     //OnPropertyChanged("TypeUsers");
  }
}

public string Name
{
  get
  {
     return _userType.Name;
  }
  set
  {
      _userType.Name = value;
      //OnPropertyChanged("Name");
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: does your underlying collection implement INotifyChange property?

Comment: Yes, I did only this property inherited from other class.

Comment: put it on the Name property in your TypeUsers class and see if that gets you better results.

Comment: I did it and same error.  I Added whole code behind in post above.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in `UserType` class.

Comment: I'm getting same error after Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in UserType class.

Comment: @enzodev I cant see OnPropertyChanged method in your `UserType` class. Remove property changed related things from everywhere else, and keep it only in `UserType` class only.

Comment: Please look now in my first post. I removed OnPropertyChanged from ViewModel class. I still have the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding directly to the WPF control (`ListBox`) and not the ViewModel. I suggest you add a property in your ViewModel that will bind to the `TextBox.Text` property, once the data changes or the user had changed the value in the `TextBox`, then the data will update and be reflected in the UI.

Also, if I remember correctly, at launch, the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` is null, so there might be a problem there too, but I'm not certain about that...

Comment: Could you plaese add some example with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem. I have also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface in Model class. I'm new in WPF MVVM and I read that this interface is implemented only in the ViewModel for connection with View. Now I have implemented in both classes and everything works great.

Thanks Everyone.